# Recover Mypassport from misapplied permissions

Tags: permissions, external-hard-drive, file-permissions

I have a good working 2TB Mypassport.

This morning I was trying to set it up as a shared drive through the network, and haven't yet had a cup of coffee I went to Permissions (instead of Sharing), I saw I had "Everyone" with full access, I panicked, I unmarked it and and applied the changes.
In a few seconds I realized my bad, I clicked "Escape" and the process apparently ended. But after that I got "Access Denied" trying to view my files.

I disconnected the drive and bring it to my own computer. I got the same Access Denied. Then I tried to recover my permissions by going directly to the Properties in context menu. I set the  permissions to the Administrator, let it run. It took like 30 minutes.
While this process was working I even accessed the drive via MSDOS command prompt and copied a few files to my hard disk.

At the end of the process, a dialog told me that I had to close all dialogs in order to see the correct permissions working. I closed everything but keep having access denied.
So I disconnected my drive, connected it back and now I get:

**"You need to format the disk in drive P: before you can use it"** !!!!!!!! :(

How could I lost everything for just this silly permissions stuff?
The drive is sure working as it is recognized as a working drive.

Now, I can't even get the permissions dialog.

If I use a recovery tool, like [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), I can see my files, yet I don't know what to do... what happened to the disk... did I lost the partition? the mbr?

**EDIT:**
Using Active File Recovery software, I can see my files, I'm even "recovering" them right now, though I don't know recover from what since they were never deleted.

My question is what could have happened to my drive with the actions I made and what do I do to restore it to its original state. I don't want to reformat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, even though being asked for formatting your disk looks critical and terminal... all I had to do was right click it again, go to properties, set the permissions to Everyone again, and that's it... all my data is back.